# android xmlpullparser get attribute same value

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

i don't know why I can't post code.
this is xml file

```
<employees>
<detail>
    <img name="jame">jame_1</img>
    <img name="jame">jame_2</img>
    <img name="jame">jame_3</img>
    <img name="natalie">natalie_1</img>
    <img name="natalie">natalie_2</img>
    <img name="phil">phil_1</img>
    <img name="phil">phil_2</img>
    <img name="phil">phil_3</img>
    <img name="phil">phil_4</img>
</detail>
```

this is xmlpullparser to get name of img

```
public class trangaXmlpullparser {
    List<name_emp> name_empList;
    private name_emp n_e;
    private String text;

    public trangaXmlpullparser() {
        name_empList = new ArrayList<name_emp>();
    }

    public List<name_emp> getName_empList() {
        return name_empList;
    }

    public List<name_emp> parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, null);
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        String attr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
                            n_e = new name_emp();
                            n_e.setName(attr);
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
                            name_empList.add(n_e);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return name_empList;
    }
}
```

this is result
[image]

so. I will get all name of img like image I post.
I just want get jame, natalie, phil in listview.
may be group attribute same value in to one. I don't know how to description it.
can xmlpullparser do it? and how to do that?
thank you for reading.

update .
this is result I follow Bhargav
this is right. but not perfect.

[image]

I want listview is 
jame
natalie
phil

Comment: to post code you need indent all code with atleast 4 spaces

Comment: can you fix code for me ?

Comment: yea post the code here Ill suggest an edit, I can't open these images in my office sadly they're blocked

Comment: I update code. please help me

Comment: post the xml file as code too instead of image

Comment: follow the code example given here http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html , according to it , you need to write a separate function for each tag you want to parse, just follow the pattern shown in the example from that page. You should be able to generate objects for the xml

Comment: I update xml file . sorry you

Comment: What about this `String attr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");` doesn't this return the attribute value for you?

Comment: it get all attribute value. I want if attribute same value , just select one of it

Comment: ofcourse thats how you're supposed to parse XML, each line `<img name="jame">jame_1</img>` will be treated as an `img` object in a `detail` object which contains array of `img`

Comment: I know. but I want with xmlpulparser can select one attribute if attribute has same value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class trangaXmlpullparser {
    List<name_emp> name_empList;
    private name_emp n_e;
    private String text;

    public trangaXmlpullparser() {
        name_empList = new ArrayList<name_emp>();
    }

    public List<name_emp> getName_empList() {
        return name_empList;
    }

    public List<name_emp> parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, null);
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            String lastAttr = ""; // Initialize a string variable to hold the last attr you passed to setName.
            String attr = "";
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        attr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
                            n_e = new name_emp();
                            if(!attr.equals(lastAttr)) { // check if the attr you just parsed now is equal to the last unique attr you parsed
                                n_e.setName(attr); // if its not equal that means this attr is not a duplicate and you can set the name
                                lastAttr = attr; // update the last attr variable to hold the last attr you just assigned to n_e.
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("img") && !attr.equals(lastAttr)) {
                            name_empList.add(n_e);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return name_empList;
    }
}
```

What I can suggest for your requirement is this,

- Hold a variable called lastAttr that holds the last attribute value you just passed to your n_e variable.
- if your attr you just parsed deoes not equals the lastAttr you are holding then pass it to the `n_e.setName` method and update the `lastAttr` variable, the code snippet is above along with comments.

Comment: i follow you. but result not like I want. I update result image in my post. please fix it. thank you very much

Comment: sorry I don't know how to upload image in comment

Comment: please help me one more time

Comment: @abcd1234 ah you don't like the spaces?

Comment: yeah. can you fix it. I just newer in java

Comment: @abcd1234 ok then if you don't want an object itself for duplicate values of the name attribute then don't create the n_e object if the `attr.equals(lastAttr)` or don't add it to the `name_empList`

Comment: how to do it. can you fix it

Comment: @abcd1234 check the edited answer, dude you need to learn to code what I just asked you to do is simple, just need to pull the scope of attr outside the switch case statement, and compare attr with lastAttr before adding n_e to name_empList

Answer (score 0):

```
public class trangaXmlpullparser {
    List<name_emp> name_empList;
    ArrayList<String> a = new Arraylist<>(); // Initialising new list
    boolean isDublicate = false; // and flag
    private name_emp n_e;
    private String text;

    public trangaXmlpullparser() {
        name_empList = new ArrayList<name_emp>();
    }

    public List<name_emp> getName_empList() {
        return name_empList;
    }

    public List<name_emp> parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, null);
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        String attr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
                            if (!a.contains(attr)) { // Checking if our list of strings contains attribute
                                a.add(attr); // We add new attribute in our list of strings
                                n_e = new name_emp();
                                n_e.setName(attr);
                            } else {
                                isDublicate = true; // if attribute repeats, the flag becomes true
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
                            if (!isDublicate) // Checking flag
                                name_empList.add(n_e); // If flag is false we add new element
                            else
                                isDublicate = false; // else we set flag to its default value
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return name_empList;
    }
}
```

There is another more beautiful solution if you realize equals() method of your name_emp. You can replace your ArrayList with a set (Set). Set automatically checks if added object is unique (using your overriden equals() method), so the only you should do is to copy Set into ArrayList (new ArrayList.addAll(set)).

Comment: Thank you. But i just mark one answer. Sorry about that.thank you ao much